# What is the degrees of freedom of metric tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, degrees-of-freedom

As $g_{\mu\nu}$ can be taken to be symmetric, it contains 10 functions of spacetime in 4 dimensions. But, why we call these 10 functions as the degrees of freedom of the metric while they are the functions of only 4 spacetime variables?

What is meant by "degrees of freedom" here?

Comment: might be a sort of duplicate:http://math.stackexchange.com/q/612159

Comment: I have already checked the link before posting the question, my question is not about how many DOFs rather why are they DOFs?

Comment: Because the 4 spacetime variables are just labels, and at each set of values of the labels you assign the 10 values of the degrees of freedom (which vary rather freely).